# Best design pattern to skip execution of code if one of the child method throws exception

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using core java to develop a testing framework. In my application I have a parent method which calls ten different child methods, where each method can throw its own exceptions. The requirement is to provide detailed log information about the execution of parent method which contains information like total time taken to execute the method, time taken to execute each child method, log any exceptions etc. I am using multiple try catch finally blocks for this.

My question is, What's the best way to skip the execution of remaining child methods if one of the child method throws an exception? For eg: If method 4 throws an exception, I want to log that exception and go to the end and log the time taken by parent method until then.

I tried using boolean variable initializing it to true at the beginning of parent method. I am checking if the boolean varible is true before executing each child method. Whenever an exception is thrown, I am marking the boolean variable false.

My psuedocode looks like this:

```
public String parentMethod(){
    boolean execute = true;
    if(execute) {
        try event1; 
        catch(Event1Exception e1)  
            log e1; execute = false; 
        finally log event 1 time taken;
    }
    if(execute) {
        try event2; 
        catch(Event1Exception e2)  
            log e2; execute = false; 
        finally log event 2 time taken;
    }
    and so on ....
    log total time taken;
```

In my actual code I have about ten different events which throw their own exceptions, sometimes more than one. With this approach, assigning execute = false for each exception caught and then again checking the value of execute seems clunky. Is there a better approach than this, without using any additional plugins?

Comment: If you have something like `for(...) { try { execute } catch { handle exception } }` then you could easily do that: `try { for(...) { execute } catch { handle exception } }`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just log the exception and rethrow it:

```
public String parentMethod(){
    try {
        try {
            ... 
        } catch(Event1Exception e1) { 
            log e1;
            throw e1;
        } finally {
            log event 1 time taken;
        }

        try {
            ... 
        } catch(Event2Exception e2) { 
            log e2;
            throw e2;
        } finally {
            log event 2 time taken;
        }

    } catch (Event1Exception | Event2Exception | ... e) {
        // Can be safely ignored
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to handle each exception separately you can just do:

```
public String parentMethod(){
    try {
        try {
            ... 
        } finally {
            log event 1 time taken;
        }

        try {
            ... 
        } finally {
            log event 2 time taken;
        }

    } catch (Event1Exception | Event2Exception | ... e) {
        log e
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way too complex when a simple single try-catch block gives perfect solution tho this problem

Comment: A single try-catch would make you not to log each event time

Comment: Uh, why downvoting?

Comment: I said in the comment why I thought it should be downvoting, but I actually reconsidered and tried to undo it. I can not do so unless you edit the answer. Make some insignificant edit and I will be happy to undo my downvoting

Comment: Done. Just added the `can be safely ignored`

Comment: Since the OP tagged [tag:design-patterns], there is one called [Convert Exceptions](http://wiki.c2.com/?ConvertExceptions) that is essentially the first part of this answer.

Comment: The ConvertExceptions pattern is not exactly like this. In this scenario you catch `e` and throw `e`. In the ConvertExceptions you catch `e` and throw `e2`

Answer (score 1):

Hi Sree what I will recommend to use method calling in a single try block. Write all the catch blocks with different exceptions at the end of this try block. Whenever any method throws the exceptions, control will directly go to the corresponding catch block, skipping remaining method calls.

For e.g.:

```
try
{
    method1(); // Exception1 occured
    method2(); // skipped
    method3(); // skipped
}
catch(Exception1 e)
{
    // control goes here
    // End timer 

    // Calculate difference
    // Store difference in global variable
}
catch(Exception2 e)
{
}
catch(Exception3 e)
{
}

method1()
{
    // start timer

    // your code

    // End timer, if no exception occurred
    // Store difference in global variable
}
```

Hope this will help. :-)

Comment: I am not sure if I'll be able to log the time taken by any child event if it throws an exception using this approach.

Comment: Yes you can calculate time also. Just you have to do is use a global variable, calculate time in method itself and store in the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the first exception, then you could execute all the events in a single try-catch block, and handle any thrown exception in the catch block.

```
try {
    event1();
    event2();
    // etc
} catch(Exception e) {
    //Handle
}
```

Otherwise start a thread for each process and handle failures by terminating all the other threads as soon as one fails.

Comment: I tried this approach, but I am not able to log the time taken by any child event if it throws an exception.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a dedicated class for executing an event with interruption and timing capabilities, then use `n` of those. Try to break up your problem in small, manageable chunks and tackle them one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are overthinking a bit. try-catch construction already gives you what you want. consider this:

```
try {
     method1();
     method2();
     method3();
     method4();
 } catch(Exception e) {
   //do error hanlig here (log it for example)
 }
```

In this case say mathods 1 and 2 executed successfully and `method3` threw an exception - The control will go to catch block and `method4` will **NOT** be executed. which if I undestood you correctly is exactly what you need

Comment: I tried this approach, but I am not able to log the time taken by any child event if it throws an exception.

Comment: Even logging the time in the catch-block?

Comment: With this approach you'll loose the time-logging unless performed **inside** `methodX()`

Answer (score 0):

A non-answer here: don't do that.

It *sounds* like you are simply violating the *single responsibility principle* here. A class/method should have **one** purpose, and one purpose only!

Meaning: it is already suspicious that you have to call 10 different other methods - in a context that so complicated that you think it is worth putting up a question here.

So, my recommendation would rather to step back and see if you can re-factor your code base to end up with less *different* method calls bundled together somehow!

And when you really can't avoid calling 10 methods, simply use multicatch:

```
 try {
   foo();
   bar();
   ...
 } catch (ExceptionA | ExceptionB | ...
```

And beyond that: you should **definitely** work on preventing code duplication. Something like this comes to mind:

```
private interface CallContext<T, X extends Throwable> {
  T execute() throws X;
}

private static <T, X extends Throwable> T runTimed(CallContext<T, X> context) throws X {
     prepare timer
     T result = context.execute();
     put timed value somewhere
     return result;
}
```

Used something like this:

```
try {
  SomeT t = runTimed(() -> return foo());
} catch (ExceptionA a) ...
```

Comment: I generally agree on following SOLID principes but the OP said that he's making a testing framework. So the purpose of the class would be "testing the behaviour of other class". Anyway we could argue about the complexity of that since you could say "Make a class that tests just a method of other class"

Comment: @Pelocho Good observation. I thought about this for a second, and interestingly enough, I created some lambda-using code this week that could come in handy here ... updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The different events I mentioned in the questions are related events like reading the input parameters, establishing DB connection and fetching relevant information from DB, creating instances of objects that I need to test, actual method calls to run against the object etc.,

Comment: Sure ... in that case, the second part of my answer is probably more what you need. But keep in mind: answers are not only written for the OP - but also for other people coming along the way. And they might find it helpful to find *other* information than just "direct" answers.

Comment: Quite cleaner with lambdas but you're still missing the execution time in case of exception